# getting error in Chrome browser: NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I'm trying to get this app to work, it was running fine, I logged in as a superuser, made a comment, but after that I just get the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']
```

it says that the problem is at line 10 in my base.html, here is my base.html file, is the bootstrap cdn link no longer valid?

line 10:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blogging!</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {# MEDIUM STYLE EDITOR#}
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>
  <body class="loader">

    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default techfont custom-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class= 'navbar-brand bigbrand' href="{% url 'post_list' %}">My Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://LinkedIn.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">New Post!</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}">Drafts</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a>Welcome: {{user.username}}</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a class='nav navbar-right' href="{% url 'login' %}">Login <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    {# The actual blog posts#}
      <div class="content container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="blog_posts">
                  {% block content %}
                  {% endblock %}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/blog.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I believe this part in views.py may be the source of the problem:

```
@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    post.publish
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=pk)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail',pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'blog/commment_form.html',{'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=post_pk)
```

thnx

Comment: Please show `urls.py`

Comment: Shouldn't this pattern `?P<pk>\\d+)$` be `?P<pk>\d+)$` instead (redundant slash)?

Comment: @Charnel that's not the issue here - `'?P<pk>\\d+)$'` (with the escaped slash) is the same as the raw string `r'?P<pk>\\d+)$'` (with the `r''` prefix).

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of your other question, because you've removed too much info here. The error is no reverse match for `Reverse for 'post_detail'` - if the error is in the template, then it will involve something like `{% url 'post_detail' ... %}`, but you haven't included that here.